# Daily synchronize demo site database to live site database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to synchronize PHP MYSQL demo site database to live site database in daily. Is there is any PHPcode for that?

Also in live site there is a daily update `xmlhandler.php` file was created. But during run time that shows a error.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in /home/www2maint/www/news/XMLHandler.php on line 32

Comment: mysql replication id your db supports it.

Comment: Can you explain ? or there is any way to update from demo database to live site database in php mysql ?

Comment: explanation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `mysqldump` and `mysqlrestore` combined with a cronjob for this. PHP is not the right tool for this.

Comment: Please explain how to do this  ?